# Create calendar Permissions in Microsoft graph API not removable by end users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We would like to create calendar permissions on all users calendar in organization which allow a service (user mailbox) to read/write on users calendars.

There is no problem to do that by using Microsoft Graph endpoint : [Create calendarPermission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-calendarpermissions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

But we would like this permission was not removable by end users. That's why we tried to use isRemovable property set to true. For example :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UPN_OF_USER/calendar/calendarPermissions
Request Body
{
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "VALID_USER_NAME",
        "address": "VALID_USER_EMAIL_IN_TENANT@TENANT_DOMAIN"
    },
    "isInsideOrganization": true,
    "isRemovable": false,
    "role": "read"
}
```

But each time we add this permission, isRemovable property is set to true.

It doesn't seems isRemovable property is readonly in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendarpermission?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Comment: Glad to be of help @Julien:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the API in my environment and it came up with the same result. I tested couple of Scenarios and found that `isInsideOrganization` is decided by the `My Organization user` and `isRemovable` is default set to `true` for all users as they can be removed/deleted from the Sharee and Delegate list except for `My Organization User` as its the deciding authority of which permissions are assigned to what user.

It is also mentioned in calendar permission resource type [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendarpermission?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) as shown below :

[image]

**Scenarios:**

1. *Create a Permission for User `inside the Organization` by providing the two parameters and not providing the parameters as well:*

   **With Parameters:**

   [image]

   **Without Parameters:**

   [image]
2. *Create a Permission for User present `outside the Organization` by providing the two parameters and not providing the parameters as
   well:*

   **With Parameters:**

   [image]

   **Without Parameters:**

   [image]

**Note :** `IsRemovable` is set to `false` only for `My Organization User` as can be seen below:

[image]